# is there a way to run my django project server as always reflect the changes?

Tags: django, pycharm

I always run my **local server** with;

```
python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
```

But there is a problem,
**I have to refresh my browser every time** that I made a change in my code. I want the server do the job of refreshing my browser automatically.

Note: I am using Pycharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin for pycharm called "Live Edit", check this link for details https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/guide/tips/live-edit/.
P.S.: you can't work with all Django project pages at a time when using live edit, but sometimes it may save you time when working on a single html page.